# BASH Script to check a folder for a specific file type and then delete the oldest one

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a BASH command (or set of commands) that will look in a specific directory and delete ONLY the single oldest file in that directory. I've looked around, but I can't quite find what I'm looking for. Hopefully someone can help me with this, because it's the last missing piece in my script. Everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Answer (score 0):

One way to delete oldest file ending with `.specific` :

```
rm -i $(ls -tr *.specific | sed q)
```

This is not very reliable if you have spaces in filenames

Comment: None of the filenames have spaces, so this might work. Which part is determining the age of the file?